# XPages: How to create link to download file from filesystem

Tags: html, hyperlink, xpages, lotus-domino

i have a pdf file in a folder and i want to download it from an xpage.

Normally this is just html like this:

```
<a href='file://10.1.0.2/folder1/myfile.pdf'>click and download</a>
```

I tested that it works using this line in a simple html file.
In my Xpage I created a computed field (HTML display) and i added the < a > as value. I see the correct link on hover but on click nothing happens. What is the problem?

Thnx

Comment: You should show the actual, generated HTML code

Comment: What browser? In addition to @Pekka웃's comment, take a look to status bar, what link browser shows.

Comment: Based on the accepted answer it looks like the same link did not work in a HTML file like you say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have recently solved this kind of problem by writing a download "servlet" as a headless XPage. For link add onclick event:

```
sessionScope.put("filepath", file);
context.redirectToPage("/_download.xsp")
```

_*download* page has *beforeRenderResponse* event `facesContext.responseComplete()` and in *afterRenderResponse* call a java code that reads the file and writes to the output stream. Something like this:

```
if (sessionScope.containsKey("filepath")){
    FileDownload.sendFile(sessionScope.filepath);
}
```

java class:

```
public class FileDownload {
public static void sendFile(String filepath) {
    File file = new File(filepath);
    if (file.exists()) {
        ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) ec.getResponse();
        response.setContentType(MIME(filepath)); // figure out the type from extension or else

        OutputStream out;
        try {
            // for the download dialog
            response.setHeader("Content-disposition",
                    "attachment; filename*=utf-8''" + java.net.URLEncoder.encode(file.getName(), "UTF-8").replace("+", "%20"));
            out = response.getOutputStream();
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            int length;
            while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            in.close();
            out.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
    }
}
}
```

Unfortunately for very large files (1Gb or so) it becomes slow, also takes memory about twice the size of the file, but I'm not sure what could I optimize here. I've tried to call `out.flush()` within the loop, but it has no effect.

Comment: Great solution! my only modification was that i added the java class as a managed bean. I think it will be possible not to redirect to the _download.xsp page this way and just call the managed bean in the onclick event (also no session var needed if this works). My only problem is that my filename is in Greek and has spaces too, i guess i have to change things here:  response.setHeader(...)

Comment: There should not any problem with Greek - it uses UTF-8 encoding. I've used it with Cyrillic and Japanese characters without problems.

Answer (score 0):

The file system is not generally exposed in Domino. The HTML root is domino data/domino/html your file needs to be in a folder below. Folder names can't contain .nsf in the name. You can configure the folder in the internet sites.

Answer (score 0):

Seams like you mix thing up

10.1.0.2 is an ipadress and that will refer to a webserver then you should add http: infront of the url instead of file:

If you want to access a local file on your computer write file://c:\path\file.ext

But there is some restrictions in the browsers to access files on server shares.

Check this Link
http://kb.mozillazine.org/Links_to_local_pages_do_not_work