# How would I implement an RFC3161 server endpoint in Domino without using a servlet?

Tags: timestamp, database-connection, lotus-domino

I'm looking to implement an RFC3161 server (Time Stamp Protocol), and I'm looking at using Domino to store the data associated with each timestamp generated.  I'd like to use Domino's HTTP service to perform the interfacing with the clients, and the BouncyCastle Java library to actually do the timestamp protocol.

RFC3161 section 3.4 defines for HTTP a particular MIME-type (application/timestamp-query) that is transmitted (as either GET or POST) to a timestamp server URI.  I would like to accept this, and return the appropriate application/timestamp-reply.

My question is, can I do this without a servlet?  I would prefer to make the timestamp database be a completely self-contained drop-into-place entity, but a servlet can only be started from the filesystem outside of the database.

I cannot find anything in the Designer help which would suggest that this is doable.

Comment: Why is it that the servlet would need to be a completely self-contained drop-into-place entity?  Seems like a weird arch. decision, unless you're offering it as a service or an add-on.

Comment: Notes/Domino are not an "application", they are a "platform" upon which you can write other applications. In the Notes/Domino parlance, what we call an "application" is called a "database" -- a collection of documents all of which are processed by the same machinery. To deploy an application on a Domino server, typically you just put the database on that server as a self-contained drop-into-place entity and set access control appropriately. But one needs the database to store the logs of the timestamps the server signed, to meet legal documentation obligations and to store the TSA signing key.

Answer (score 1):

Well, one way would be to use an xPage as a servlet. Here ([XPages: How to create link to download file from filesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20545579/xpages-how-to-create-link-to-download-file-from-filesystem/20588770#20588770)) I give a recipe as a solution for a different problem.

Basically you enter in xPage *beforeRenderResponse* event `facesContext.responseComplete()` and in *afterRenderResponse* get the output stream and write whatever output you need.

You can also create and deploy the servlet as an OSGi plugin. A bit more regular way, a bit more hassle as well.